# Как лучше настроить раздачу Интернет в локальной сети?

Tags: роутер, маршрутизация, доступ

Соединение от провайдера через PPoE.
Имеем роутер Zyxel Keneetic Extra.
Так же внутренняя сеть диапазон не стандартный 220.100.0.0 - 220.100.255.255
Еще в сети поднята Active Directory на базе Windows Server.
Zyxel выдает диапазон для локальной сети 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

Как лучше раздать локальную сеть Интернет для пользователей, чтобы они на своих рабочих станциях имели доступ к локальным серверам и одновременно доступ в Интернет без ограничений по портам и протоколам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, прошли сутки и никто не смог ответить, как разрешить данную проблему.

Как я писал ранее, что сеть большая, ничего менять нельзя. А решается проблема просто:

1. Ставим обычный свич
2. Заводим на него интернет с роутера
3. К свичу цепляем маршрутизатор и еще один компьютер для организации ISA прокси сервера (оба компа с двумя сетевухами, одна смотрит в сеть 192.168.0.1 вторая в локальную сеть 220.100.0.0 - 220.100.255.255)
4. На клиентах ставим ISA клиент и они и в домене и в Интернет
5. Если кому из локальной сети нужен прямой доступ в Интернет, то используем статический IP с указанием маршрутизатора.

Вот это дешевое решение, без дополнительных затрат и покупок.
А самое главное экономится мое время, за которое мне дополнительно работодатель не доплачивает.

Comment: Конечно проще поставить 1000 клиентов, чем один раз поменять диапазон адресов на сервере DHCP:)

Comment: Да причем здесь 1000 клиентов? В инет ходят через терминал. Один раз настроил терминал и все.

Comment: Обычный свич, два компьютера и четыре сетевухи к ним на помойке нашли, если без дополнительных затрат и покупок?

Comment: Вы не поверите но, да таки можно найти на помойке 2 компьютера и сетевухи, ну почти. ;) По крайней мере роутить немного интернета этого хватит. В любом случаи в масштабе предприятия это бесплатно. И тем более сильно дешевле чем переводить всю эту халабуду на правильные адреса.

Comment: Для сопряжения с инетом одного терминала всего 4 устройства? Маловато будет!

Answer (score 2):

Исправить дурной локалкин диапазон на приличный и общепринятый 192.168.0.0
Иначе, в Японию у вас интернет ходить не будет в частности.

В роутере вырубить DHCP. На контроллере домена организовать переадресацию DNS, верно настроить DHCP, чтобы в качестве шлюза по умолчанию отдавал адрес кинетика.

Comment: Добавлю небольшое пояснение. В IPv4 сетях существует четкое разделение на локальные и внешние адреса. Поэтому если у вас в сети больше одной машины вам следует использовать диапазоны предназначенные для локальных сетей. Это отчасти обусловлено вопросами безопасности, а так же связанно с не иллюзорной ограниченностью количества IPv4 адресов. Более подробно можно просветиться например на Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81

Comment: Нельзя изменить диапазон локальной сети, потому что сеть большая, более 1000 рабочих станций и десяток серверов. Ваше решение больше подходит для маленькой домашней сети или офиса.

Comment: @antony 1. Сеть по маске /16, это 65534 компьютеров. Вам мало?

Comment: Еще раз повторяю, дело не количестве компьютеров, дело в том, что нельзя менять диапазон.

Comment: @Antony ну тогда - наслаждайтесь граблями. У вас что, на тысяче машин статика забита? Вон из профессии!

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю вашей фамильярности? Зачем показывать свою некомпетентность в вопросах сетей и настройки серверов?
Не тратьте мое и свое время зря.

На локальном сервере установлен локальный DHCP, если вам не понятно.

Comment: @Antony замечу, что не я засадил в локалку диапазон адресов Интернета, и не я не могу назвать объективных причин для исправления ситуации кроме "сеть большая"

Comment: Понятно, значит у вас не хватает опыта работать с такими большими сетями. Меня интересует мнение опытного специалиста с большим опытом работы. Поэтому просьба отвечать по существу. Мой опыт работы более 15 лет в сфере IT, последние 5 лет на междуродной бирже UpWork. Вот попробуйте поработать там, потом вступайте в дисскуссии на тему - вон из професии.

Comment: @Antony с высоты своего большого опыта поясните тогда, пожалуйста, чем оправдано такое нарушение стандарта?

Comment: @ComBin а вы когда-нибудь устраивались на работу в компанию, с уже существующей сетевой инфраструктурой?

Comment: @Antony понятно. Никакого. :) В прочем я вас понимаю, видимо изначально это творение планировалось эксплуатировать как некую закрытую сеть и выхода в интернет там не планировалось. Рискну предположить что это какой-нибудь завод или подобное "старое и большое".

Comment: @ComBin бинго ;) вы правы, оно самое :)
Изначально, планировалась, как закрытая сеть.